# Keep Receiving a 424 Debug Error w/ File Name

Tags: vba, object, debugging

Please see the bold code below. The debugger says that it is what's causing the 424 "Object Required" error. Any insight/help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```vb
Sub GraywolfPlanful()

    Dim sForecastFile, sUploadFile, sTab As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sForecastFile = GraywolfWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks.Add
    sUploadFile = GraywolfWorkbook.Name
    Range("A1") = "Company"
    Range("B1") = "Department"
    Range("C1") = "Location"
    Range("D1") = "Segment"
    Range("E1") = "Account"
    Range("F1") = "Year"
    Range("G1") = "Month"
    Range("H1") = "Amount"
    Range("A2").Select
    Windows(sForecastFile).Activate
    sTab = Format(Sheets("00_No Department").Range("C1"), "yyyy-mm mmm") & "Project Forecast"
    
    
    For i = 4 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Select
        Range("F6").Select
        Do Until (Range("C") = "End" And Range("D") = "Subtotal Other G&A")
            If Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row) <> "" Then
                Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row, "AD" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
                Windows(sUploadFile).Activate
                Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(12, 0)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row, "B" & ActiveCell.Row + 12) = "Test"
                Windows(sCurrentFile).Activate
            End If
        Loop
    Next i
    Windows(sUploadFile).Activate
    GraywolfWorkbook.SaveAs CurDir & "\Test File Graywolf"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    
End Sub
```

Comment: code formatting overrides bold formatting - you nee to specify the row where the error occurs ...

Comment: I figured out the reason. For some reason the Dimensions: sForecastFile & sUploadFile needed to = ActiveWorkbook.Name